# Google Maps API for Flash - clickable Polyline

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have added event listener that is fired each time a polyline is clicked. How can I identify the polyline that was clicked? Is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is possible. Here is the code:

```
public function cutToEnd(event:MapMouseEvent):void
{           
    var clickedPolyline:Polyline = event.feature as  Polyline;
}
```